# Browser control not showing content from document stream

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to display binary content (eg. image, pdf file, etc) in a browser control. As I want to avoid first writing the content to a temporary file, I'm doing:

```
var browser = new WebBrowser() {
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
    DocumentStream = new MemoryStream(content)
};
this.Controls.Add(browser);
```

where `content` is a byte array whose content may vary.

However, when I do the above, the content is not being displayed (just an error icon).

Does `DocumentStream` work in such cases or do I need to go through the temp file path?

Comment: If the link to the image/PDF file/URI is already in the HTML, then it will work (meaning, `content` is a HTML document read as a byte array). You cannot pass in a PDF as byte array, of course. The WebBrowser will present a PDF document if Internet Explorer has a plug-in for that.

Comment: @Jimi No. `content` is just the byte array and not the HTML document.

Comment: Then add the Image/PDF file as a link to a basic HTML document. Add this header to the template: `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv='x-ua-compatible' content='IE=edge'> ...other stuff... </head>`. Then pass the HTML document as a byte array (you just need a placeholder in the HTML template that you can replace with `string.Replace()`).

Comment: See also: [PDFObject](https://pdfobject.com/)

Comment: I forgot to mention that you can embed an Image (and other objects) as a byte array converted to a Base64 string. I'm not sure it can be done with a PDF using the WebBrowser control. Maybe with an `.js` library, inside a IFrame.